# Use SQL to query javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, search

Is there a way to run an SQL query against javascript objects to find data within them? Specifically I'm looking for a way to query a few objects (each representing a table of data) and perform a join on them.

I figured this was a long shot, but worth asking nonetheless.

Comment: Do you mean some interface on the browser that accepts SQL?

Comment: Please could you provide a more detailed description of your problem along with some sample JavaScript objects.

Comment: @n8wrl No, not an interface, it's more for the behind-the-scenes manipulation of data, so I can take in javascript objects (say from an ajax call) and perform advanced queries on them before displaying to the user.

@a'r No sample js objects yet, I wanted to know if there was a way to query js objects before building a solution that relied on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLike also is good to emulate SQL or linq syntax:

http://code.google.com/p/sqlike/

Answer (score 3):

Try [JSLinq](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/)

See this Example from the site:

```
var myList = [
        {FirstName:"Chris",LastName:"Pearson"},
        {FirstName:"Kate",LastName:"Johnson"},
        {FirstName:"Josh",LastName:"Sutherland"},
        {FirstName:"John",LastName:"Ronald"},
        {FirstName:"Steve",LastName:"Pinkerton"}
        ];

var exampleArray = JSLINQ(myList)
                   .Where(function(item){ return item.FirstName == "Chris"; })
                   .OrderBy(function(item) { return item.FirstName; })
                   .Select(function(item){ return item.FirstName; });
```

Comment: Never heard of this, but I like the looks of it. Doesn't appear to do joins though.

Comment: Well someone claims on their site he has developed something like this, no ide if its true but you can try to contact him. See folowing link: http://jslinq.codeplex.com/discussions/41842?ProjectName=jslinq

Answer (score 2):

Never used it before, but a quick search on Google yields [LINQ to Javascript](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/).  While it isn't SQL Syntax, it allows you to do SQL Like things on Javascript objects, or so it appears.  You may also want to check out this [question about LINQ and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478038/what-is-the-leading-linq-for-javascript-library)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`async-linq`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-linq) which support both sync and async LINQ operations in JavaScript and feature on-par with C# version. You can get it by `npm install async-linq`.

**Sync operation**

```
linq([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
    .where(function (v) { return v % 2 === 1; })
    .select(function (v) { return v * 100; })
    .run();
```

**Async operation**

```
linq(['abc.txt', 'def.txt', 'xyz.txt'])
    .async
    .select(function (filename, index, callback) {
        fs.stat(filename, function (err, stat) {
            callback(err, err ? null : {
                filename: filename,
                size: stat.size
            });
        });
    })
    .run(function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There's TrimQuery - hasn't been updated for some time, but it's solid.
http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/TrimQuery