# Given a JSON Object, How to find a item based on a Key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Given a JSON object like:

```
var data = {items: [
{value: "21", name: "Mick Jagger"},
{value: "43", name: "Johnny Storm"},
{value: "46", name: "Richard Hatch"},
{value: "54", name: "Kelly Slater"},
{value: "55", name: "Rudy Hamilton"},
{value: "79", name: "Michael Jordan"}
]};
```

How can I do something like this:

```
datagood = data.where(value == 55)
```

Is something like that possible with JS/jQuery? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[jQuery's `grep` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) lets you filter through an array:

```
var datagood = $.grep(data.items, function (item) {
    return item.value == 55;
});
```

If you want more powerful utilities, take a look at [this SO question on JS LINQ libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478038/what-is-the-leading-linq-for-javascript-library).

Alternatively, [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) is also useful for array/object manipulation.

Answer (score 4):

jLinq? http://www.hugoware.net/Projects/jLinq

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com/docs#where) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#where) libraries _.where() and _.find() functions:

```
var res1 = _.where(data.items,{value:"55"});
var res2 = _.find(data.items,{value:"55"});
```

The difference between these two functions that _.where() returns all matched records, and _.find() - only first record.

```js
var data = {items: [
    {value: "21", name: "Mick Jagger"},
    {value: "43", name: "Johnny Storm"},
    {value: "46", name: "Richard Hatch"},
    {value: "54", name: "Kelly Slater"},
    {value: "55", name: "Rudy Hamilton"},
    {value: "79", name: "Michael Jordan"},
    {value: "55", name: "Another Rudy Hamilton"}
]};

var res1 = _.where(data.items,{value:"55"});
var res2 = _.find(data.items,{value:"55"});

document.write('-.where(): ',JSON.stringify(res1),'<br>');
document.write('-.find(): ',JSON.stringify(res2),'<br>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = {items: [
{value: "21", name: "Mick Jagger"},
{value: "43", name: "Johnny Storm"},
{value: "46", name: "Richard Hatch"},
{value: "54", name: "Kelly Slater"},
{value: "55", name: "Rudy Hamilton"},
{value: "79", name: "Michael Jordan"}
]};

// using underscore.js http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/
var t = _(data.items).find(function(x) {
  return x.value == 55;
});

JSON.stringify(t) ; //# => {"value":"55","name":"Rudy Hamilton"}

// using pure javascript
var find = function(items, f) {
  for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    if (f(item)) return item;
  };
}

t = find(data.items, function(x) {return x.value == "55";});

JSON.stringify(t) ; //# => {"value":"55","name":"Rudy Hamilton"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my **one-liner** solution for you:

```
let result = data.items.find(x => x.value == '55');
```

**Full Example:**

```js
var data = {items: [
{value: "21", name: "Mick Jagger"},
{value: "43", name: "Johnny Storm"},
{value: "46", name: "Richard Hatch"},
{value: "54", name: "Kelly Slater"},
{value: "55", name: "Rudy Hamilton"},
{value: "79", name: "Michael Jordan"}
]};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    let result = data.items.find(x => x.value == '55');
console.log(result);
  document.getElementById('person').innerHTML = result.name;
})
```

```html
<div id="person"></div>
```