# Need Something like C# Expression Tree on Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

Consider something like this.

```
const myFunc = (x) => x.Property1;
let obj = {
 Property1: "value1",
 Property2: "value2"
};

console.log(myFunc(obj)); // output: value1
```

I need something like this:

```
console.log(whatINeed(myFunc, obj)) // output: **Property1**
```

Is it possible to achieve this requirements ?!

what will be the body of "whatINeed" function ?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478038/what-is-the-leading-linq-for-javascript-library

Comment: @Rajesh I want to know which propery of my obj is tried to read. I want to get "Property1" in my sample.

Comment: Guess you have to write some kind of "parser" for that. That shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @AnestisKivranoglou thanks for your comment. I think, you misunderstood. Lamda syntax isn't my issue. I need to find out which property of my Model (obj) is tried to read. 'Property1' in this sample.

Comment: This question is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `myFunc.toString()`, it will give you `"(x) => x.Property1"`. You can then write a parser for that, shouldn't be too hard. It will be hard if you want full-feature like C#.

Comment: It's a kind of solution. Waiting for any other solution... thanks.